# columnDefs not working

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I am trying to add an additional column in the datatables api but it is not at adding it, I tried this which had not effect

```
columnDefs:[{
               data: null,
               defaultContent: "<a href='javascript:void(0)'>Open</a>",
               targets:-1
            }]
```

And when I tried this,

```
 columns: [
            { data: "RequestStatus", name: "RequestStatus" },
            { data: "RequestNo", name: "RequestNo" },
            { data: "RequestDate", name: "RequestDate" },
            { data: "Requestor", name: "Requestor" },
            { data: "Item", name: "Item" },
            { data: "RequiredDate", name: "RequiredDate" },
            { data: "ItemStatus", name: "ItemStatus" },
            { data: "Technician", name: "Technician" },
            { data: "DeliveryMethod", name: "DeliveryMethod" },
            { data: "LastModified", name: "LastModified" },
            { data: null, defaultContent: "<a href='javascript:void(0)'>Open</a>" } // this one
           ]
```

I started getting error in angularjs file

> Error: n[m] is undefined

Comment: Could you add the HTML for your table or your source data?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/33/ It's Working, the problem must be in your data, please show your html